# Typescript method overload with generics

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-generics

I've searched several documentations and blogs, but no one ever covers this example..

```
export interface IConfigurationProvider {
    getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames>(key: TKey): string;
    getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames, TValue extends object>(key: TKey): TValue;
}

export enum ConfigNames {
    SomeSetting,
    AnotherSetting
}

export class ConfigurationProvider implements IConfigurationProvider {

    public getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames>(key: TKey): string;
    public getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames, TValue extends object>(key: TKey): TValue;
    public getSetting(key: any): any {
        // what the heck do I do here???
    }
}
```

So, in most overload examples people would do something like:

```
public getHero(name: string);
public getHero(name: string, skill: string);
public getHero(name: string, skill?: string): Hero {
    if (!skill) {
        return this.heroes.find((hero: Hero) => hero.name === name);
    }
    return this.heroes.find((hero: Hero) => hero.name === name && hero.skill === skill);
}
```

But in my case, the only difference is the return type which is designated by the supplied generic type definition.  So how would I implement a base implementation that can handle either case if I don't have access to `TValue`?  In C#, `TValue` is an actionable item, but due to the way Typescript does overloading, I can't go: `if (typeof TValue === undefined)`

If this can't be achieved, then that's fine, but the code compiles and if I do `let configItem = config.getSetting<ConfigNames, Date>(ConfigNames.SomeSetting);` the intellisense correctly infers that I'm supposed to get a Date object back.  So, like C#, there are things that compile, but don't work when run, so hopefully this isn't one of those cases.  So if anyone knows how to correctly implement the base method here, I'd like to know.

UPDATE: 
For the one that requested an explanation of my intent behind this use case and for others reading this...

In C# I would have methods like the following

```
public string GetSetting<T>(TKey key) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key.ToString());
}

public T GetSetting<TKey, T>(TKey key) where TKey : struct, IConvertible
{
    var settingString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key.ToString());
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(settingString);
}
```

This allows the ability to store config items as json objects so I can store a config item as "11:00:00" and then do: `var timespanSetting = config.GetSetting<ConfigNames, TimeSpan>(ConfigNames.SomeTimeSpanSetting);` <-- This is ideally what I'd like to be able to do.  If I have to create 2 methods with different names I will, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I imagine you're limited to implementing the base method `getSetting` without knowledge of what the passed in type of `TValue` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two method signatures is particularly well-behaved.  Let's put aside the overload issue for now.  Suppose you broke them out into two separate methods:

```
getSettingOne<TKey extends ConfigNames>(key: ConfigNames): string;
getSettingTwo<TKey extends ConfigNames, TValue extends object>(key: TKey): TValue;
```

So, `getSettingOne()` doesn't use `TKey` at all.  That's... weird.  It will likely be inferred as `{}` no matter how you call it, and even if you explicitly set `TKey` to some value when you call it, it would have no effect on anything.  What purpose does it serve?  What are you trying to do with this method?

Then, `getSettinTwo()` at least uses `TKey` since it's the type of the `key` parameter.  But now, `TValue` is only used in the return value.  Since the *caller* specifies the values of the type parameters (or they are inferred from values the *caller* passes), this method signature says something like "I will return a value of any type the caller wants".  That's not really possible to implement properly.  Only the [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) type is safely assignable to every type... so I interpret `getSettingTwo()` as a method that takes a `TKey` and throws an exception or never returns or something.  Since that can't be what you mean, what are you trying to do with this method?

---

So, I don't know how to implement each signature separately (other than throwing an exception), I *really* don't know how to implement them as an overloaded function.  But if the question is just "how can I make an implementation signature for this", the answer is that the implementation signature just needs to be at least as permissive as all the call signatures.  You can give it type parameters also.  So the following will type-check, and "give you access to `TKey`" at least as much as either of the call signatures does:

```
public getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames>(key: ConfigNames): string;
public getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames, TValue extends object>(key: TKey): TValue;
public getSetting<TKey extends ConfigNames, TValue extends object>(key: TKey): TValue | string {
  throw new Error(); // useless
}
```

But there's still no good way to implement that thing (which is why I just throw an error there).  My suggestion is for you to revisit your method signatures and change them to what you actually mean.  I don't think you've given enough information in your question for anyone to help you do that.  Maybe you want to edit your question or create a new one with this information?  Until then, good luck!

---

UPDATE:

Okay, now I have some idea of what you're trying to do.  It looks like you want to call the function one of two ways... one that just gets a JSON string, and another that parses that JSON string and asserts that it is of some caller-specified type.

Note that the latter call is not type-safe at all... the caller could call

```
let configItemDate = config.getSetting<ConfigNames, Date>(ConfigNames.SomeSetting);
```

or

```
let configItemRegExp = config.getSetting<ConfigNames, RegExp>(ConfigNames.SomeSetting);
```

and the compiler will think `configItemDate` is a `Date` and that `configItemRegExp` is a `RegExp`, even though at most one of those can be true.  Remember that the [type system is erased at runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure), so both calls get transpiled to `config.getSetting(ConfigNames.SomeSetting)`... that means `configItemDate` and `configItemRegExp` will be the same value at runtime.

Sometimes you do want to do an unsafe type assertion in TypeScript, but it's best to do it with great care.  Having a method that purports to return whatever type the caller wants without having a way to verify that is riskier than I'd like.  But, whatever, let's say you want to do it that way.

The only way to get what you want accomplished with a single method is to provide some way *at runtime* to distinguish between the call that returns a string and the call that returns an object.  That means you'd need to introduce, say, a new parameter whose value controls this:

```
getSetting(key: ConfigNames, parseJSON?: true);
```

If you pass in the `parseJSON` parameter as `true` you get an object, if you leave it out, you get the JSON string.  It could (possibly) be done with overloads like this:

```
public getSetting(key: ConfigNames): string;
public getSetting<TValue extends object>(key: ConfigNames, parseJSON: true): TValue;
public getSetting<TValue extends object>(key: ConfigNames, parseJSON?: true): TValue | string {
  const json = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key.toString());       
  return (parseJSON) ? JSON.parse(json) : json;
}
```

But at that point, the overloads aren't buying you much.  More straightforward would be two have to completely different methods like:

```
getSetting(key: ConfigNames): string;
getSettingAs<V extends object>(key: ConfigNames): V;
```

which would be implemented separately.

---

Again I reiterate that `getSettingAs()` is not type safe, since the caller can plug in anything to `V` and it will appease the compiler without affecting anything at runtime.

Case in point, I sincerely doubt that any normal JSON parser will produce a valid JavaScript `Date` object.  You could possibly make a custom JSON parser that does this. And if you're starting to customize JSON parsers, it leads to yet another possible way of doing `getSetting()`... pass in an optional JSON parsing function which is known to convert to the desired type:

```
public getSetting(key: ConfigNames): string;
public getSetting<V extends object>(key: ConfigNames, jsonParser: (json: string)=>V): V;
public getSetting<V extends object>(key: ConfigNames, jsonParser?: (json: string)=>V): V | string {
  const json = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key.toString());       
  return (jsonParser) ? jsonParser(json) : json;
}
```

This is now type safe, but relies on the caller passing in a valid JSON parser.

---

Hope one of those ideas help.  Notice how I completely removed `TKey` from all of that, since you don't seem to be using it.  Also notice that the `enum` you gave was a numeric but you seem to expect the `key` to maybe be a string?  If I were you I'd focus on getting your code working at runtime (maybe writing it in pure JavaScript) and then try to add typings for it.  Or, if not, maybe one of the above typings will be useful to you. In any case, good luck!

Comment: Yeah the key: ConfigNames was a typo, that should've been TKey

Comment: Updated in response to your added info

Comment: I'm going to accept this on the basis that the conclusion for me is simply that Typescript cannot achieve specifically what I want.  I do appreciate the ideas proposed though.

Answer (score -6):

Typescript will be translate to Javascript， so there's no method overload in typescript.

you can use parameter object like this:

```
getHero (param:  { name: string; skill?: string; }) {
  if (!param.skill) {
    return ... 
  }
  return ...
}
```

Comment: [This answer is wrong](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)